# Driver.quit() is not closing any of my tabs after my test is run

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests

I am running a test in Selenium with junit4 which opens multiple windows during the test. I then want to close the driver (all windows) after the test but for some reason this isn't working. I am new to java/junit and Selenium so apologies if the resolution is obvious

```
    //I start the Webdriver here outside of my test
    public WebDriver driver = TestContext.StartDriver(TestContext.getDashboardsUrlSaml());


    //My test iterates around 7 times through parameters set (params not included in question)  
    @Test 
    public void login () throws InterruptedException, ParseException {
    String currentHandle= driver.getWindowHandle();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date) new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("01/01/2030 00:00:00");  
    //expirationTime
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName,content,"rfqasv0003d.chicago.cme.com","/sso/accountstatus",date,true);
    driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Cookie has been added for: " + role);

    driver.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();
    
    System.out.println("Logged in successfully for: " + role);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    System.out.println("The dashboards required for " + role +" are: " + dashboards);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   
    String[] reqDashboards = dashboards.split("\\|");     
    List<String> requiredDash = Arrays.asList(reqDashboards);       
    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-selector']/select")));
    List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
    
    ArrayList<String> displayedDash = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    
    for (WebElement visibleDash: options) {
        String visDash = visibleDash.getText();
        displayedDash.add(visDash);
    }   
         
    System.out.println("The dashboards displayed are: " + displayedDash);
    System.out.println("Count of dashboards visible is: " + displayedDash.size());
    
    assertEquals(requiredDash.size(), displayedDash.size());
    assertTrue(requiredDash.containsAll(displayedDash));
    assertTrue(displayedDash.containsAll(requiredDash));
        
    //logout
    driver.findElement(By.className("user-name")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-5")).click();
    
    driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
    
    }   

//This is where I'm trying to close my driver
//My test is running with no errors however my driver stays open after the test has been run        
    public void finish () {
    driver.quit();
    }
        
}
```

Comment: You need to add one `before` and one `after` annotations, see https://www.javatpoint.com/testng-annotations

Comment: I don't think  the `finish()` method in above code is called at all ,there is no call to this method or are you calling it as part of teardown script,add a debug point in `finish()` method to check if it is being executed ,

Comment: Hi Abhay - you're correct I wasn't! If I wanted to call the finish method after it is set, how do I do that? I tried finish(); after googling but it isn't working

Comment: Annotate `@AfterMethod ` annotation to finish method, it should execute that
The annotated method will be run after each test

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary I am using Junit - I know there's after and before but I don't have that setup currently for my test, was hoping to avoid. Thanks for your answer, back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you are not running that method
Try to use annotation `@AfterMethod` for the quit method
Like this:

```
@AfterMethod
public void finish () {
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
    }
```